# Change class and text of button based on post result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the class and text of the button that was clicked based on the result from an ajax post.  The page has many buttons, none have IDs (although I could add them if it's for sure needed).  I have the following javascript:

```
$('.ph-button').click(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $(this).closest('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
            selected.push($(this).html));                                    
        })
    })

    console.log(selected);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
        data: { arrayOfClasses: selected },            
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            //need the if statements here I think
            console.log(data);                                        
        }
    });
});
```

It works and gives me a 0 or 1 as `data`.  I need to change the class to `class='ph-button ph-btn-blue` and the text to `Watched` if `data` is 0 and change the class to `class='ph-button ph-btn-grey` and the text to `Watch` if data is 1.

I tried using `$(".ph-button").toggleClass("ph-button ph-btn-blue");` but it changed the class of all the buttons on the page and didn't seem to do it like I need.

I'm guessing toggleClass isn't what I need and i'm not sure how to address the button that was clicked instead of all of them.  Here are the two possible buttons:

```
<td><button class='ph-button ph-btn-blue'>Watched</button></td>
<td><button class='ph-button ph-btn-grey'>Watch</button></td>
```

SOLUTION:

```
$('.ph-button').click(function () {
    var selected = [];
    var btn = $(this);
    $(this).closest('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).html());                                    
        })
    })
    console.log(selected);    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
                data: { arrayOfClasses: selected },            
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 1) {
                        btn.toggleClass("ph-btn-grey ph-btn-blue").text('Watched');
                    }
                    if (data == 0) {
                        btn.toggleClass("ph-btn-blue ph-btn-grey").text('Watch');
                    }
                }
        });

   });
```

Comment: You can try addClass removeClass and `.text()` methods to change text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a temporary variable referencing the button, so you can use it later on in your AJAX `success` callback:

```
$('.ph-button').click(function () {
    var selected = [];
    var btn = $(this);
    $(this).closest('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).html());                                    
        })
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
        data: { arrayOfClasses: selected },            
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data == "0"){
                btn.toggleClass("ph-button ph-btn-blue").text('Watched');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, just using $(this) inside the success function didn't work but using the variable created earlier 'btn` did work.  Thanks!